# CSHTML Page getting rendered as a static Page

Tags: iis, razor, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-6

I made a Website using Web Matrix.

I added that site to IIS web server under websites in Windows 8.

I added MIME Type for .cshtml file as text/html in IIS web server?

Razor code is not getting executed and getting rendered as plain text in browser.

Am I getting error because of wrong MIME type ?

How should I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly why it's not showing correctly. The MIME type shouldn't be added, that comes directly from the Handler Mappings section, so just delete the MIME type you added and it should work fine.